# Как построить график

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста, как построить график следующего типа

[image: график]

на графике изображено 8 осей выходящих из центра центр это координата 0.
Возможно ли использование сторонней библиотеки для построения такого типа графика или все делать вручную.(Сторонняя библиотека предпочтительней из за красоты рисунка).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать [MSChart](https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=14422) в связке с [WindowsFormsHost](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost?view=netframework-4.7.2)